# How to select and dial contact from input with iOS Workflow app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, setup

I would like to know if it's possible to use the new Workflow app to do the following.

My company has 50 stores. Each store is in my contacts as:

Store 101

Store 102

Store 103

Store 104

etc. etc...

I have to call one of these stores frequently, for whatever reason. Each store only has a single phone number listed to be available to call.

I would like a workflow that takes input and selects and calls the contact.

For example I want to launch the workflow, have it prompt me for the store number only, and pass "Store (input)", determine which contact that would be and dial its number.

So:

1. Launch workflow app shortcut
2. Shortcut prompts for store # only
3. Parses text "Store" plus input variable #
4. Dials number for the contact

Comment: This is possible but you would have to manually enter all the stores info to begin with for it have a database to query from so why not just add a group to your contacts and simply search that group

Comment: Ohhhh sorry. I just reread it. Disregard. I'll work on for you

Comment: It's Exactly one more click than what you are looking for, but I would simply use `spotlight search` for this. It's already built in.  From the home screen just drag your finger down until the Spotlight Search box appears and type the store number, the contact will be exposed click it and click the phone number field and your call to the store will be dialing.  Also Settings > General > Spotlight Search will allow you to reorder "contacts" in the search results if you need to, as I recall contacts is number 1 or 2 by default which should be fine.

Comment: Sure Spotlight search would almost be just as fast, but there's an added click where I have to change keyboard to numeric, then search, and wait the few seconds for it to take place, click again on the contact, then phone #. With workflow app, in theory, click app once, type store number, enter, it dials for me

Comment: @BrentonTaylor i was able to create an applescript that is nothing out of the ordinary, prompt a dialog box, take the text you input & pass it to the clipboard then query your contacts with companies names that contain the string. Easy. The hard part....calling that number. This can be done, but we're looking at a full blown application at this point & this honestly feels like its becoming a job. I would suggest just keep your contacts open on start up and that way you can search directly or look for 3rd party apps. BTW, keyboard shortcut for spotlight is command⌘ + spacebar

Comment: Hmm I thank you for that hard work but this question was for the new iOS app called "Workflow": Workflow: Powerful Automation Made Simple by DeskConnect
https://appsto.re/us/2IzJ2.i
Did I perhaps post this question on the wrong Stack Exchange site?

Comment: I looked at workflow after you mentioned in the title, It's not useful to me it adds more overhead in my opinion.  To answer your question tho yes you have the correct stack exchange site, but the original question should contain the full exact name of the app, I wondered yesterday if I was even looking at the correct app at first.  And SECONDS for spotlight search?  Oh please I have a 64gb phone that never has anything but instant spotlight search results.